# Compare multiple columns in SQL Server returning largest version less than or equal to a given value by product

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Using SQL Server 2008, I am attempting to write a select statement which will query the data below and return one row per Product, finding the largest product version less than or equal to a given version number.

Sample Data

```
Product  Major  Minor  
=======  ====== ====== 
Widgets  10     1      
Widgets  6      6      
Widgets  4      92     
Gears    9      2      
Gears    10     0      
Tires    8      3      
Tires    7      14
```

Given version = Major: 10  Minor: 0

Expected Results

```
Product  Major  Minor  
=======  ====== ====== 
Widgets  6      6      
Gears    10     0      
Tires    8      3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select product, major, minor
from (
select *, 
row_number() over(partition by product order by major desc, minor desc) as rn
from tablename
where major <= @someval1 and minor <= @someval2) t
where t.rn = 1
```

You can use the `row_number` function substituing the values for variables @someval1 and @someval2.

Answer (score 0):

I usually find making a single number out of  Major: 10 Minor: 0 makes it clearer to read.  So something like:

```
SELECT p.Product,  p.Major,  p.Minor
FROM Products p
JOIN (SELECT sub.Product, 
             MAX(sub.Major * 10000 + sub.Minor) AS MaxVersion
      FROM Products AS sub
      GROUP BY sub.Product) AS Maxes
ON p.Product = Maxes.Product
     AND p.Major * 10000 + p.Minor = Maxes.MaxVersion
WHERE Maxes.MaxVersion <= @Major * 10000 + @Minor
```

I usually do the same with Year * 100 + Month